# package development without restarting

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I develop `Sublime 3` packages like this:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class RelativeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello World")
```

I need to reload sublime after every editing in it to see result of changing in work.

How to get working changes in plugin without exiting the sublime and reopening it?

I believe that it is possible, because for example sublime get changes on the fly without reloading when you edit key mappings.

**Update1 :**
When I press save after changing file, I got message in console:

```
Writing file /Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/relative/relative.py with encoding UTF-8 (atomic)
reloading plugin relative.relative
```

**Update2 :**
I am using symlinks to store `Packages` and `Installed Packages` in `Dropbox` folder.

**Update3:** 
My os is `OS X version 10.8.5`

Comment: Plugins should be reloaded when you save them. Well, they do need to be at the top level. E.g. `Packages/MyPlugins/plugin.py`. If it's nested, it won't reload automatically. It's also possible to run into issues if you are using multiple files. But based on your example, you are only using a single file. When you save, is there anything in the ST console?

Comment: Yes I got message: `Writing file /Users/maks/Dropbox/SublimeText3/Packages/relative/relative.py with encoding UTF-8 (atomic)`

Comment: Is filePath `Packages/relative/relative.py` ok for plugin to be reloaded automatically when I save it?

Comment: Are you symlinking to your drop box folder. I recall people having issues with that before. I think it's come up here on stackoverflow before. I'll try to find the issue, or perhaps someone who knows will come by. If you are, it's probably worthwhile to include that in your question. More details cn make things easier to solve.

Comment: ok, updated main text.

Comment: @efr What's your OS? This works well on Windows.

Comment: @lhuang OS X version 10.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know why, but after removing symlinks to Dropbox of `Packages` folder, it started to work as expected: after saving got message in console:

```
reloading plugin relative.relative
```

And can see new behaviour without reopen sublime3.